# Python paramiko max characters returned

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, tty

I am running a paramiko script with python where I use linux `top` in the call:

```
        cmd = "top -cbn2 -d 0.1 | awk '/^top -/ { p=!p } { if (!p) print }'"
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        top_outlines = stdout.read().split('\n')
        top_errlines = stderr.read().split('\n')
```

But I am only getting ~80 characters returned when I know there should be more. How can I get the full lines returned?